# Can real scalar fields break charge conjugation symmetry?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, symmetry-breaking, charge-conjugation

Is it possible to have a Hermitian term in a Lagrangian that breaks $C$ symmetry and is made up of only real scalar fields?  I thought that real scalar fields would always have to be even under $C$ but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a complex scalar field, charge conjugation $\cal{C}$ is defined by:

$\qquad\cal{C}\hat\phi(x)\cal{C}^{-1}=\eta\,\hat\phi^\dagger(x)\quad$ and 
$\quad\cal{C}\,\hat\phi^\dagger(x)\cal{C}^{-1}=\eta^*\hat\phi(x),$

while $\eta$ is a complex number with $|\eta|=1$. Now, for a neutral field, i.e.,   $\phi^\dagger=\phi$, according to the definition above, $\eta$ has to be real valued and thus $\eta=\pm 1$. That is, a real scalar field does not necessarily need to be even under charge conjugation.